# How to set different keyboard for login screen on iPad

Tags: keyboard, ipad, login-screen

This is iPad/iOS - specific.
I want a login keyboard that includes the numbers row by default.  I'm using Swiftkey but it only shows up inside running apps, not the login screen.
Is it physically possible to assign a different keyboard to the login screen?

Comment: I think 3rd party keyboards are not allowed at the login screen for security reasons,

Comment: @TomGewecke  wouldn't surprise me.  Oh, well